# 'Str' item does not support item assignment --PyMongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I'm working in a Jupyter notebook to build CRUD functionality for a MongoDB server using Pymongo.  Whenever I get to my Create function, Python throws a "'str' does not support item assignment" as I pass in my data to the Pymongo insert function.

The base CRUD code so far is:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

class AnimalShelter(object):
    """ CRUD operations for Animal collection in MongoDB """

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        # Initializing the MongoClient. This helps to 
        # access the MongoDB databases and collections. 
        self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@localhost:54933' % (username, password))
        self.database = self.client['AAC']

# Complete this create method to implement the C in CRUD.
    def create(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            self.database.animals.insert(data)  # data should be dictionary
            return True
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to save, because data parameter is empty")
            
# Create method to implement the R in CRUD. 
    def read(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            self.database.animal.find(data)
            return True
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to find, because data parameter is empty")
```

And the main portion that is being called to test those CRUD function is:

```
from module4_markw import AnimalShelter


def __main__():
    username = 'aacuser'
    password = 'acc355!'
    aShelter = AnimalShelter(username, password)
    data = {
    'age_upon_outcome' : '3 years',
    'animal_id' : 'Z756330',
    'animal_type' : 'Dog',
    'breed' : 'Chihuahua Longhair Mix',
    'color' : 'Brown/Black',
    'date_of_birth' : '2013-11-18',
    'datetime' : '2016-12-28 18:43:00',
    'monthyear' : '2016-12-28T18:43:00',
    'name' : 'Franklin',
    'outcome_subtype' : '',
    'outcome_type' : 'Adoption',
    'sex_upon_outcome' : 'Neutered Male',
    'location_lat' : 30.7595748121648,
    'location_long' : -97.5523753807133,
    'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks' : 166.111408730150
}
    aShelter.create(data)
    aShelter.read(data)
```

Jupyter then gives me a string of what I take are exceptions that are being triggered?  I work mainly with C++ and Java, still learning Python.  Where am I going wrong exactly?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-263240bbee7e> in <module>
----> 1 main()

<ipython-input-1-a916c4e4b5e4> in main()
      7     aShelter = AnimalShelter(username, password)
      8     data = [""]
----> 9     aShelter.create(data)
     10     aShelter.read(data)

~/module4_markw.py in create(self, data)
     14     def create(self, data):
     15         if data is not None:
---> 16             self.database.animals.insert(data)  # data should be dictionary
     17             return True
     18         else:

/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py in insert(self, doc_or_docs, manipulate, check_keys, continue_on_error, **kwargs)
   3180             write_concern = WriteConcern(**kwargs)
   3181         return self._insert(doc_or_docs, not continue_on_error,
-> 3182                             check_keys, manipulate, write_concern)
   3183 
   3184     def update(self, spec, document, upsert=False, manipulate=False,

/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py in _insert(self, docs, ordered, check_keys, manipulate, write_concern, op_id, bypass_doc_val, session)
    642         write_concern = write_concern or self._write_concern_for(session)
    643         blk = _Bulk(self, ordered, bypass_doc_val)
--> 644         blk.ops = [(message._INSERT, doc) for doc in gen()]
    645         try:
    646             blk.execute(write_concern, session=session)

/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    642         write_concern = write_concern or self._write_concern_for(session)
    643         blk = _Bulk(self, ordered, bypass_doc_val)
--> 644         blk.ops = [(message._INSERT, doc) for doc in gen()]
    645         try:
    646             blk.execute(write_concern, session=session)

/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py in gen()
    626                     doc = _db._apply_incoming_manipulators(doc, self)
    627                     if not (isinstance(doc, RawBSONDocument) or '_id' in doc):
--> 628                         doc['_id'] = ObjectId()
    629 
    630                     doc = _db._apply_incoming_copying_manipulators(doc, self)

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: IDK of any problems defining `__main__` in a `jupyter` notebook (although, I don't think I've seen that before), and I'm wondering how you call it.  Do you run all the cells in order?

Comment: As it turns out, main needed to be run in the same cell as the def.  Also, restarted the Jupyter notebook in the terminal also helped.